# iOS Facebook api, apprequests sent but not receiving?

Tags: ios, facebook, apprequests

I'm currently working on an iOS app, and I use apprequests to bring up the dialog to send request. I can see everything working fine (I got the dialog complete thing) but user is not getting the request! I'm working with a test FB app (not public), I'm thinking if there's something I'm missing on setting up the FB app? Or is there a specify permission I have to enable?

Here is a little piece of my code:

```
-(void)appRequestsWithMessage:(NSString )message {
NSMutableDictionary params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: message, @"message", nil];
    [facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
       andParams:params
     andDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: This answer fixed it for me: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8348164/184561

Answer (score 1):

To allow App Requests to be shown in Facebook, you have to enable "App on Facebook" in Apps Settings and supply a "Canvas URL" and a "Secured Canvas URL".

Comment: Where to set this canvas URl. I cant find it in the Settings of my App page

Comment: Choose you App > Settings > Facebook Canvas > Canvas URL

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the receiving user as a tester on your Facebook app admin page? As long as you're in sandbox mode, only users added as testers (or any other position) can see, interact with and receive requests from our app.

Check the settings page for your app.

Comment: The sending and the receiving are are developer of the FB app. Still no luck with it :(